# The file PHPExcel_Shared_String.php is missing in the includes folder

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have tried the change function and it did NOT work.

I am working with PHPExcel and I keep on getting this error
"The file PHPExcel_Shared_String.php is missing in the includes folder."

it is not showing up as a fatel error or anything like that. It is just printing out on the screen

I am using PHPExcel Version 1.8.0.

IOFactory.php

```
/** PHPExcel root directory */
if (!defined('PHPEXCEL_ROOT')) {
    /**
     * @ignore
     */
    define('PHPEXCEL_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
    require(PHPEXCEL_ROOT . 'Autoloader.php');
}
```

mypage.php

```
include('../../../assets/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');
```

Autoloader.php

```
class PHPExcel_Autoloader
{
    /**
     * Register the Autoloader with SPL
     *
     */
    public static function Register() {
        if (function_exists('__autoload')) {
            //    Register any existing autoloader function with SPL, so we don't get any clashes
            spl_autoload_register('__autoload');
        }
        //    Register ourselves with SPL
        return spl_autoload_register(array('PHPExcel_Autoloader', 'Load'));
    }       //function Register();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHPExcel is showing error on Remote Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720467/phpexcel-is-showing-error-on-remote-server)

Comment: I tried that before I had posted on here. Still got the same error "The file PHPExcel_Shared_String.php is missing in the includes folder."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i had done to fix my issue.

http://www.ozzu.com/programming-forum/phpexcel-t109746.html